# TFS Pending Changes keyboard commands in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS2012 with TFS2010 (which may or may not matter).

I cannot seem to get any of the keyboard commands that *should* work with the Pending Changes window to, y'know, work.

I've tried the steps listed [here](http://alexmg.com/post/2009/09/05/Comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-Pending-Changes-in-TFS.aspx), and I've tried binding keys to ever "CompareWith" commands listed in the keyboard dialog. The only ones that actually seem to do anything are the File.* commands, but those operate on the open file, and not the Pending Changes window.

I've seen that commands like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (check-in) work, but they don't appear in the Keyboard settings.

Does the new window in VS2012 have its own set of keyboard settings that are set somewhere else? I'm trying to get to the point of have an keyboard-only workflow for Comparing, the Excluding or Undoing.

**Update**:
This is really strange. I can actually see the shortcut keys in the right-click dialog, but pressing them does nothing. I then tried changing it to a chord, and I get the error message: "The key combination (Ctrl+Shift+Q, Ctrl+Shift+Q) is bound to command (Tfs.ContextPendingChangesPageExcludeChanges) which is not currently available"

**Update 2**: I found [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/06/team-explorer-2012-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx), which has some more shortcuts listed, but not that actually do operations on the individual files. For quick reference, here's his list:

```
Shortcut    Team Explorer Page
Ctrl+'      Search
Ctrl+0,H    Home
Ctrl+0,P    Pending Changes
Ctrl+0,M    My Work
Ctrl+0,W    Work Items
Ctrl+0,B    Build
Ctrl+0,R    Reports
Ctrl+0,D    Documents
Ctrl+0,S    Settings
Ctrl+0,A    Web Access – team home page
F5          Refresh
Ctrl+Up     Move focus to the previous visible section header
Ctrl+Down   Move focus to the next visible section header
Alt+Left    Navigate backward
Alt+Right   Navigate forward
Alt+Home    Focus the navigation control
Alt+0       Focus the page top level content
Alt+[1-9]   Focus the visible section [1-9] level content
Alt+Up      Focus the previous visible section content
Alt+Down    Focus the next visible section content
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug with key bindings in some Team Explorer pages in VS 2012 RTM.  This has been fixed for the next VS 2012 update.

-Chad